Wildcard character—noun or adjective?
What precisely is 'wildcard' in 'wildcard character', the latter being frequently used in texts on EDP, such as descriptions of command line syntax of programs.
In particular, is 'wildcard' essentially the compound adjective 'wild-card', thus an adjective itself, or rather 'wild card' shortened to 'wildcard' (noun), then used as attributive noun here ?
At the time of this writing, major online dictionaries include 'wild card', but not 'wildcard', neither as noun nor adjective. For example, see Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

Peter, your use of “precisely” intrigues me, as though you may have a specific intended thing you hope to do once you get a “precise” answer. May I please ask what the use-case is here—meaning, what practical real-world problem are you trying to solve that getting a "precise" answer to your question will allow you to move past?  What good does knowing that “precise” answer do for you? Might you have something interesting in mind?

My use of 'precisely' here is wrong ?

No, it is not wrong in any fashion whatsoever. But given your example of descriptions of the command line syntax of computer programs, it occurred to me that you might be considering making use of such part-of-speech assignments computationally in natural language processing work such as part-of-speech tagging and dependency or constituency parsing.

ODE (courtesy of Google) certainly gives wildcard as a spelling variant. As do  CD, Collins and AHD. I don't see any mention of the compound (open, hyphenated [as it often is used prenominally in the UK], or solid) being an adjective.

@EdwinAshworth Given that several dictionaries provide "answers" both to the spelling question and to the part-of-speech question that differ from one another, I do not see how either question asked is easily "answerable" by "a" dictionary—plus the most detailed treatment is behind the OED paywall. Pray correct me if I am wrong, but to me this seems a stellar opportunity for ELU to provide professional answers that guide the asker through these various and otherwise contradictory dictionary conflicts towards a clearer understanding. We can and should provide actual expert answers, no?

@tchrist There seems no debate in dictionaries about POS. And the first three dictionaries I checked in allowed the solid compound, contrary to OP's claim. And the adjective vs attributive noun debate has been well covered.

Wild card and variants wildcard and wild-card are all nouns. So you have an attributive noun in wildcard character.
See Merriam-Webster — wild card:

wild card noun
3 usually wildcard ˈwī(-ə)l(d)-ˌkärd : a symbol (such as ? or *) used in a keyword database search to represent the presence of
zero, one, or more than one unspecified characters

At Merriam-Webster you can also read Nouns That Look Like Adjectives and apply some tests for attributive nouns. As M-W summarizes:

Attributive nouns do some of the same work that adjectives do, but
that doesn’t mean they're not nouns. Think of them as nouns that
learned how to multitask.


Sense 3 of the (paywalled) online OED entry for wild card, wild-card, wildcard confirms M-W: “3. Computing. More fully wild card character. Originally: a symbol (or group of symbols) that represent zero, one, or more than one unspecified symbols, used as a means of specifying one or more files by name, typically in a programming command such as ᴅᴇʟᴇᴛᴇ. Now chiefly: a symbol in a search string that represents zero, one, or more than one unspecified characters. The most common wild cards are *, which usually represents zero or more[…]”

"wild card" as a phrase of course derives from card games. I don't know if it was contracted to one word once it became a computer term, or before that.

@StuartF — From what I can see, the OED found perhaps the earliest instance of the one-word wildcard — as a computer term and in 1984.

'Wild-card' always noun, and never an adjective, really? Inspired by terms like 'home-made', three-year-old' etc. I'd think the same formation process may apply/ happen to compound nouns, too, resulting in ready-made adjectives.

@Peterש Yes, that's right. Some of the many syntactic tests for nouns-vs-adjectives include: §1 A predicate test with a copula or other linking verb, which most nouns fail but most adjectives pass (e.g.: a simple character > a character is simple VS a wildcard character > a character is ❌ wildcard). §2 A morphology test where you see which of inflecting as a noun or as an adjective produces a grammatical result (e.g.: some characters are wildcards VS some characters are ❌ wildcarder / ❌  more wildcard than others).

@Peter §3 A noun-phrase–ordering test because any noun adjuncts must follow all adjectives in a noun phrase, so if you can swap two modifiers then both are of the same word-class not different ones (e.g.: a new wildcard character VS a ❌ wildcard new character). Other useful syntactic tests for this purpose include a substitution test, a coördination test, and testing for the semantic role. In all these tests most attributive nouns will all either pass or fail whereas most attributive adjectives will do exactly the opposite of that. Together the preponderance of evidence is dispositive.

@Peterש Another syntactic test is an intensifier test: most nouns don't like being modified by intensifiers or adverbs, but most adjectives are fine with that. In the same fashion, most nouns can be modified by an adjective but most adjectives cannot be and attempting to do so yields something ungrammatical. Do you see how this business of using syntactic tests works to figure out what something's word class is? There can be individual exceptions here and there, but the overwhelming results will always skew one way or the other. That's the scientific way to determine the answer.

@tchrist I'm having trouble seeing all this without an example... can you explicitly do one of these syntax tests? I'm not sure what the test would look like... a phrase with a blank in a modifier place that works for both noun and adjective, and another where it doesn't work for one of those? I'm also worried about how polysemy could confuse things here - a word that is both a noun -and- separately an adjective that is not a noun-attribute, eg 'green' the color and 'green' the place in golf where you putt).

@Mitch I already gave concrete examples in the comments above. This is not really something to be discussed in comments, so you'd best take that question either to chat or by asking a new question about it, or both. Otherwise to justly answer you, I cannot help but fear that all you may first need to know about generative-transformational grammars and of deep and surface structure shall never fit comfortably into Fermat’s last margin. :)

@tchrist oh I didn't realize the '❌'s were your transformation examples. Reading them again.


wild-card, adj. U.S. (of a sports team) qualifying for championship play-offs by winning an arbitrary playoff among
second-place teams or by winning the most games along teams that did
not qualify for play-offs.
...
[1972, so called from the supposed resemblance of such a team to a
wild card, a playing card of arbitrary denomination]
Clarence L. Barnhart et al. (eds); The Second Barnhart Dectionary of
New English (1980)

The two citations provided both have "wild card" in quotation marks, neither hyphenated: "wild card" slot and "wild card" team.

I suggest a simple analysis.
First,

Cambridge
Adjective: a word that describes a noun or pronoun

Second:

ngram
Google ngram shows that wildcard and wildcard character have come into use after 1980, the latter accounting for about half the usage of the former.

The time is therefore right to accept wildcard as a word as used in the Cambridge definition of adjective. Furthermore it is a word acting as defined - as an adjective describing character.
The development of the etymology and the hyphenation of the word, although illuminating, do not detract from this simple argument. It is a word describing a character, so is an adjective.

The word wildcard does not “describe” the head noun character in such noun phrases as a simple wildcard character; rather, it “categorizes” or “classifies” it. You can easily use at least half a dozen well-known syntactic tests to prove that this is still a noun here and not an adjective. That’s how you know for certain that this is here only a noun adjunct, not an attributive adjective.

@tchrist: Which tests? Always eager to learn sth.

@Peterש See my three comments listing seven or eight of these useful syntactic tests on Tinfoil Hat’s answer to your question given above.

At Ngram Viewer’s Notes you can see how Google uses the noun wildcard both as usual and attributively. e.g. “You can also specify wildcards in queries...” and “...dig a little deeper into phrase usage: wildcard search, inflection search...”

Wildcard (often, wild card, rarely wild-card, but they all mean the same) is essentially a noun - which originally just had the literal sense of a playing card that does not have any particular value but that can be used to represent any other card.
In recent decades (particularly in computer "pattern matching" contexts), it's metaphorically applied to text characters (often, * or ?) representing a range of possible values, and to entrants in a competition who didn't "qualify" in the same way as other contestants.
Metaphoric uses are usually as a noun adjunct / attributive noun. In such contexts, it's an adjective, modifying an immediately-following "head noun" such as character or entrant. If the "head noun" isn't explicitly present, it should be contextually obvious what type of thing is being referenced, if not an actual playing card.

In case it's not obvious, I should point out that "words" aren't inherently "nouns", "verbs", "adjectives", etc. Such classifications apply to actual usages in context. For example, someone responsible for managing an annual competition might say to this year's winner...

"Next year I'll wildcard you, so you won't have to qualify to compete".

...where it's being used as a verb.

You have one mistake: attributive nouns modifying other nouns do not in so doing become adjectives. They're still nouns, just ones that happen to be functioning as modifiers. Never confuse a word-class, meaning its category or part of speech, with its grammatical role or syntactic function. These are different things. There are various possible syntactic tests for all these things. See the OED about this lemma.

I reject that criticism. The cited usage is as an adjective, and I don't accept that the eight characters in the text string "wildcard" should be labeled as a noun. That's the whole point of me giving an example showing those same eight characters being used as a verb. If you fundamentally disagree then by all means downvote the answer. I'm not gonna change my mind, no matter what anyone says.

In support of my position, look at how many decades were wasted trying to program computers to understand and generate "natural language" before we had sufficient compute to tackle the problem using neural nets. Natural language doesn't actually have a "fixed" set of categories that can be fully covered by rules. For most purposes here on ELU, terms like noun, verb, adjective, adverb are more useful than "modifier". But either way, any such labels apply to instances of use, not the characters in the "word" itself.

Who said that a noun used attributively as an adjective can't be called an adjective? If something functions as a modifier, it can function as an adjective. I agree here with FF: "words" aren't inherently "nouns", "verbs", "adjectives", etc. Such classifications apply to actual usages in context.

The OED says this is a modifier use as a noun. It is not an adjective. Predicate tests help here: the ? character is "a" wildcard, not that it is *wildcard.  You can also only modify it using adjectives, not by using adverbs, so it cannot itself be an adjective.

@Lambie Anyone who has ever studied linguistics enough to know the crucial difference between word class (its part-of-speech category) and grammatical role as a syntactic constituent,  that's who. These simply are not the same thing once you get beyond the simplistic primary school instruction we give small children. We are a site for professional linguists etc. so a child's model does not suit us here.

They are all the same: In grammar, a noun adjunct, attributive noun, qualifying noun, noun (pre)modifier, or apposite noun is an optional noun that modifies another noun; functioning similarly to an adjective, it is, more specifically, a noun functioning as a pre-modifier in a noun phrase. Wikipedia

@tchrist: I did actually search Google Books for the possibility of a wildcard card, but apparently no-one has gone that far in print. So far as I'm concerned, though, any such usage would be pretty much on a par with a PIN number. Whatever - "noun, adjective, modifier,..." are all just labels for classifications that attempt to describe how we can break down the elements that make up utterances. They're not really worth arguing too much about - a label is either useful or not, depending on the exact context.

Labeling an attributive noun an adjective (rather than a modifier) would upend things. The OED routinely has citations for nouns in which they are used attributively. For example, helicopter pilot, helicopter station, helicopter method and  helicopter carrier all appear in citations under helicopter (n.)

@DjinTonic: Speak for yourself. It doesn't upend anything for me to call a word used as an adjective an adjective, even if that same word (sound, string of character, whatever) can be used as a noun or a verb in other contexts (where I would call it a noun or a verb). But I weary of pedantry, and refer you back to my point that linguists and grammarians were completely unable to provide programmers with an accurate enough description of English to allow computers to reliably handle natural language. I  have yet to see chatgpt come out with an idiomatically unacceptable construction.

@DjinTonic Just how does it upend things?

@Lambie Just as noun phrases like house plant containers, child care costs, and list separator punctuation all contain no adjectives whatsoever, the ᴏɴʟʏ adjectives in the following sentence are common and valid: “$ and £ are fairly common example currency symbol characters, but because * and ? are potentially valid wildcard characters, officially they are pattern syntax characters.”

@Lambie For one, what do we tell students of English, that helicopter in He's a helicopter pilot is both a noun and an adjective?

@DjinTonic: "helicopter" there is an "adjective of type" (the type of pilot associated with the noun "helicopter"). As opposed to an "adjective of quality", such as "qualified" or "experienced" (using what are usually called "past participles" as adjectives). But it's all just terminology and analytical frameworks - the actual subject matter (intimately familiar to confident native speakers) is unaffected by the labels.

@FumbleFingers You just gave away the game: whenever an attributive adjunct is classifying the head noun by assigning a type or category to it instead of describing some quality, then is always a noun, not an adjective. This is trivially provable by at least a half-dozen well-known syntactic tests.

You all should strictly distinguish between 'word' (written/ seen, spoken/ heard, or something else, such as a skin sensation; broadest sense anyway) and 'term'. A 'term' is a unit grouping, among other things potentially, at least one identifier ('word') and some meaning.

@DjinTonic No, you tell them that the noun (helicopter) in helicopter pilot is a noun used as an adjective. Just like all attributive nouns. I just don't see what CGEL et compagnie get their knickers in a twist over this.

@Lambie Never tell them that because that is incorrect because It once again mistakes the word class for the syntactic function. You tell them that is a noun whose grammatical role here is not as a subject or object but rather as an attributive adjunct. If you continue to tell them the wrong thing then they will make trivial errors like misplacing its relative position within a longer noun phrase per my NP-ordering syntactic test I gave earlier, and so will produce ungrammatical results like *some wildcard punctuation new nice characters. They'll fail at all the other syntactic tests, too.

@tchrist That's all you can say? Never tell them that because it's incorrect? Because you say so? If adjectives precede nouns, they'd problably do nice, new wild-card punctuation characters. And your example is far from "trivial", requires knowing wild-card is an adjective but can easily be properly aligned.

@Lambie No, wild-card/wild card/wild card is NEVER an adjective. You keep using "used as adjective" in a fundamentally confusing and wrong way that ignores a hundred years of science.  Please stop bickering about this here: you have made this personal by claiming it's a "because I said so" thing, and that is very untrue: I gave scientific proof.

wild-card
in American English
(ˈwaildˌkɑːrd)
adjective

of, constituting, or including a wild card
informal
of, being, or including an unpredictable or unproven element, person, item, etc Collins Dictionary


@Lambie As with pronunciation matters, you should not blindly believe dictionaries for grammar matters.  For one thing, that is simply not what they are good at. But for another they sometimes use outdated or simplified models for the sake of presenting a watered-down, shortened, and simplified version of reality to learners despite those reductions leading them completely out of step with the science of linguistics. So grammar and  pronunciation in my first sentence and learners in this one are not "nouns used as adjectives" no matter what you might find some learners dictionary say.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
